# Understanding docker diff

Tags: docker, diff

I do not understand the output of 'docker diff'. See below for details.
This is my Docker version:

```
$ docker version
Client version: 1.7.1
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 786b29d
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.1
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 786b29d
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

I have a Jenkins image with the following content in /var/jenkins_home:

```
$ docker run -it --rm jenkins ls /var/jenkins_home
init.groovy.d
```

I then start Jenkins to populate Jenkins data dir:

```
$ docker run --name app -d jenkins
```

After Jenkins is started I call into the container to list the files:

```
$ docker exec app ls /var/jenkins_home
Download metadata.log
hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml
identity.key.enc
init.groovy.d
jobs
nodeMonitors.xml
nodes
plugins
secret.key
secret.key.not-so-secret
secrets
updates
userContent
```

Ok! Lots of new files. Now I want to ask Docker what files are changed or created:

```
$ docker diff app
C /tmp
A /tmp/hsperfdata_jenkins
A /tmp/hsperfdata_jenkins/1
A /tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-war--any-
A /tmp/jffi6440203232202129886.tmp
A /tmp/jna--1712433994
A /tmp/winstone874928832634242220.jar
C /var
C /var/log
C /var/log/copy_reference_file.log
```

So why is it that 'docker diff' isn't showing me the new files in '/var/jenkins_home'?
What am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
- Morten Green Hermansen, Fanitas

Comment: What storage driver are you using? May you provide 'docker info'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Dockerfile for the Jenkins image](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/1f0d2b7d5b69aed1b0af7916ca46d35b249c1c86/Dockerfile#L14), you will notice that there is a [VOLUME](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#volume) directive that makes the location `/var/jenkins_home` a volume mount point.

As a result, any data written to `/var/jenkins_home` is stored on the volume mount point, and is not stored on the *container filesystem* itself.

The [docker diff](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/diff/) command will only show differences on the *container filesystem* and won't show anything related to content of volume mount points.

The same applies for other docker commands such as [commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit), [cp](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cp/) and [export](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/export/).

Comment: Thanks Thomas! That was the bit I was missing.